# Suppose a word is picked at random from this sentence. What is the distribution of the length of the word picked?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Suppose a word is picked at random from this sentence. What is the distribution of the length of the word picked?

I was wondering if anyone could link me to a page that will help me understand what 'distribution' means? I tried looking for one myself but I didn't really find anything that helped me understand this question and how to do it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It might be easier to use "probability mass function" $p(k)$, defined for all $k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, and being the probability the chosen word has length $k$.  So $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p(k)=1$.  In your case, it looks like the longest word is "sentence," which has length 8, so $p(k)=0$ for $k>8$.  This is what is meant by "distribution."  Formally, you could also give the cumulative distribution function (CDF) in terms of the mass function, but it is easier in this context to just give hte mass function.

Answer (score 1):

As for [probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), I would read the wikipedia page.

I'm going to assume you mean this sentence:

> Suppose a word is picked at random from this sentence.

If I call $N$ the length of a word chosen at random (each word equally likely), then notice that the possible values of $N$ are $\{1, 2, 4, 6,7,8\}$

Now, we list the probability of each value
$$P(N = 1) = P(\text{Choose (a)}) = \frac{1}{10},$$
$$P(N = 2) = P(\text{Choose (is)}\cup\text{Choose (at)}) =  P(\text{Choose (is)})+P(\text{Choose (at)}) = \frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10} = \frac{2}{10}$$
where the second equality is true since the events are disjoint.
The rest are calculated similarly, and the distribution table of $N$ is
\begin{array}{r|c}
n&P(N = n)\\\hline
1&\dfrac{1}{10}\\\hline
2&\dfrac{2}{10}\\\hline
4&\dfrac{3}{10}\\\hline
6&\dfrac{2}{10}\\\hline
7&\dfrac{1}{10}\\\hline
8&\dfrac{1}{10}
\end{array}